# NAT Gateway with Internet Gateway and lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless-framework

We use elastic beanstalk to run our main application out of EC2, we also have an RDS instance in that VPC. Those instances have public IPs so it can use a standard internet gateway to access the internet. No problems there.

Now I have created a lambda function, associated it with the 3 subnets corresponding to the 3 AZs the EC2 instances live in. Everything is still good. My lambda can connect to those resources just fine.

My problem is I need my lambda to reach the internet. Normally I'd route the subnets it's in to 0.0.0.0/0 and route it out through a NAT gateway. However, because the EC2 and RDS instances in the subnets of the VPC my lambda is associated with have public IPs putting a NAT gateway in breaks their internet connectivity. How should I go about giving my lambda internet access, without breaking the IGW for the other Ec2 instances?

I was thinking of maybe creating 3 new subnets within the 3 AZs, associating that with my lambda function, create a NAT gateway in each AZ subnet, make the corresponding routes for each subnet. If I did that would my lambda still be able to access the EC2\RDS instances within the other subnets? I have a lambda sg and an ec2 sg and the lambda sg is permitted access to the ec2 sg. Hopefully this makes sense!

Answer (score 0):

As it is not possible to attach public IP addresses to Lambda functions, you have to launch them in private subnets and forward internet traffic to a NAT gateway/instance to let your functions access the Internet.

It looks like you have only created public subnets in your VPC. As you have already suggested, you need to create private subnets that hosts your lambda functions.

- Create 1 public and 1 private subnet per AZ.
- Launch NAT Gateways in public subnets.
- Update the routing table of the private subnets and forward all internet traffic to the NAT GW.

> **Private subnet RT**
>
> 0.0.0.0/0 --> NAT GW
>
> **Public subnet RT**
>
> 0.0.0.0/0 --> IGW